# how to remove uploadify control in div correctly with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, uploadify, jsrender

i use a div with uploadify control in it,then use jsrender bind data to edit,but when i want to remove  the div to cancel edit in IE,a error says "object required",then failed.who knows why,please tell me,thanks!
the main code:

```
    function edit(){
      $("#id").html($("#editTmpl").render(data));
      uploadify init
    }
    function cancelEdit(){
      $("#id).remove();
    }
```

the html code:

```
<div id="editTmpl" type="text/x-jsrender">
    <div class="editRow rowEdit communityDraw">
                    <dl>
                        <dt>drawing：</dt>
                        <dd class="divDrawingsContainer" data-id="{{>CommunityId}}">
                            <div class="attachmentToolbar"><span>
                                <input id="file_upload-{{>CommunityId}}" type="file" /></span></div>
                            <div id="uploadingFiles-{{>CommunityId}}"></div>
                            <div id="divDrawingsDisplayBody-{{>CommunityId}}"></div>
                        </dd>
                    </dl>
                    <i class="clearfloat"></i>
                </div><div class="editRow rowEdit communityDraw">
                    <dl>
                        <dt>drawing：</dt>
                        <dd class="divDrawingsContainer" data-id="{{>CommunityId}}">
                            <div class="attachmentToolbar"><span>
                                <input id="file_upload-{{>CommunityId}}" type="file" /></span></div>
                            <div id="uploadingFiles-{{>CommunityId}}"></div>
                            <div id="divDrawingsDisplayBody-{{>CommunityId}}"></div>
                        </dd>
                    </dl>
                    <i class="clearfloat"></i>
      </div>
<div>
```

Comment: Can you please provide your HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the syntax error in this function

```
function cancelEdit(){
      $('#id').remove();
    }
```

Comment: there is no syntax error because if i use not uploadify,there is no problem,but thank you

Comment: If you think there is an error in the line, then please provide the correct code in your answer.